# Lexical or processor issue: boost/config/user.hpp' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-redux, react-native-ios

When i run my react native app in Xcode, it shows an error  "boost/config/user.hpp' file not found" . And also when i run the application using the command "react-native run-ios" ,I got an error in terminal ,

```
"Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/sample2.app/Info.plist" Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist " .
```

How can i solve this. I am a bigginer in react native app development.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I'm having same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's related to this boost package: `./node_modules/react-native/third-party/boost_1_63_0/boost/config`

- Remove `third-party` folder from path: `/node_modules/react-native/third-party/`
- Re-run the Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any updates to run on your machine/xcode? I had this issue when I had pending macOS Sierra updates to install.

I installed the updates which caused my mac to restart, I then ran `npm install` and tried to build again and it succeeded.

Versions:

- macOS Sierra: `10.12.6`
- Xcode: `8.3.3`
- react: `16.0.0-alpha.12`
- react-native: `0.47.1`

Answer (score 0):

Some packages are not installed properly. Just delete node-modules forder with rm -rf node-modules and run again (npm install or yarn install).