# xcode 'boost/config/user.hpp' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, boost, react-native, npm

I'm using Xcode 9, everything was fine. but after I upgrade my React-native version to 0.46, and upgrade my React to 16.0.0 alpha12. and re-run my project, Xcode gives me an error `'boost/config/user.hpp' file not found`, I use `brew install boost` to install boost. but it doest work. 
It seems like something wrong with react-native, because I can use Xcode to create a new iOS project and works fine, but when I use 'react-native init newProject', It gives me the same error.

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Comment: No, I followed many instructions, but I still have the error, I had to downgrade my react-native version to 0.44

Comment: I see, I as well end up downgrading my react-native to 0.44.0. Looks like it's the only version that works fine.

Comment: this may be the answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623624/lexical-or-processor-issue-boost-config-user-hpp-file-not-found/45650123#45650123

Comment: 0.44 works fine, I wasted too mush time struggling with 0.46.

Comment: Any solution? till date?

Comment: Shamin's answer works fine for me @ShoebSiddique

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just remove the cache and the third_party folder in react-native in node modules

```
 rm -r ~/.rncache
 rm -r <your-project>/node_modules/react-native/third_party
```

Comment: Remove **rncache** and Delete _"boost-for-react-native"_ in **ios > Pods** folder, then run `pod install`

Comment: I don't .rncache, and removing third_party directory didn't help

Comment: Removed third party folder but it regenerates each time iOS build starts

Answer (score 5):

For those who are using react-native version > 0.57

```
rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.facebook.ReactNativeBuild
rm -r <your-project>/node_modules/react-native/third_party
```

Comment: neither folder exists for me

Comment: it's finally helped me. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I just run the command : `npm install` and fixed the issue..

Answer (score 2):

for me it was key to remove the ios/Podfile.lock file after removing the ios/Pods/ folder

Answer (score 0):

Hope this also helpful

Deleting the `Podfile` for boost, and running `pod install` again

Comment: where do i find the Podfile for boost?